# JQuery: Don't search within children

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

Let's say I wan't to find all the elements that have a `data-view` attribute but I there can be elements that have `data-view` which are parents to other `data-view` elements. I don't want the children to be in the search, I want the parents.

```
$('[data-view]').each(function() {});
```

with the following HTML:

```
<body>
   <div data-view="app">
       <div data-view="hello1">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div data-view="job">

   </div>
</body>
```

It should return only `app` and `job` and not `hello1`. I've had no luck in using the `.not` selector has it stops selecting any `[data-view]` elements.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var target_attr = "[data-view]";
$(target_attr).filter(function () {
    return !$(this).find(target_attr).length;
}).each(function () {
    // Whatever
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gEVyk/1/

This will find all elements with the `data-view` attribute that have 0 *descendants* with the same attribute. In your case, that's `hello1` and `job`.

If you're sure they're only `<div>`s, you should use `div[data-view]`.

This will find all elements with the attribute that have 0 *parents* with the same attribute:

```
var target_attr = "[data-view]";
$(target_attr).filter(function () {
    return !$(this).parents(target_attr).length;
}).each(function () {
    // Whatever
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ue9w9/1/

In your case, that's `app` and `job`.

Comment: I got it working with `return $(this).find(target_attr).length;` instead of the negated version. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel Well, your question was confusing in the first place: "but there can be elements that have `data-view` which are parents to other `data-view` elements, which I don't want to have in my search." But then you say: "It should return only `app` and `job` and not `hello1`." But according to the first thing, it should only return `hello1` and `job`. You should explain better which ones you want - elements that don't have descendants of the same, or elements that don't have ancestors of the same - they're 2 totally different things.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry about that. After re-reading it, it's indeed confusing.  I'll update it just for the sake of it, but nonetheless your method works.

Comment: @Daniel No problem :) So technically, you only want the `app` element in this case, right? Because it's the only parent. So in that case, you were right that you wouldn't want the `!` in my first example

Comment: I want the `app` element and `job` element. The issue is purely around not grabbing the children elements of the same selector.

Comment: @Daniel Okay, it's still confusing because you used the word "parents". But `job` isn't a parent - it's alone. My first example won't work for you. My second one will though - it looks for elements that don't have any `[data-view]` parents/ancestors...which is `app` and `job`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('[data-view]:not([data-view] [data-view])').each(function() {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5P8X/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `$("body").children("[data-view]")`. The `.children()` will only look at the immediate descendents of the selected element.

Comment: This will not work for all the cases.. The OP has given an example where in the elements are children of the body . But that might not be  the case.

Comment: True - after re-reading the question, it seems undefined and Ian have answers that will better match this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('[data-view]:not([data-view] [data-view])').each(function() { ... });
```